# Visual Studio 2010 not running tests/have to restart VS NUNIT testing

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to run some tests but when I try to, the test never completes, it gets stuck in progress, and the only way I can stop it is to restart VS, I have googled, and cant seem to find what I'm looking for.

```
[TestMethod()]
        public void fahrenheitToCelsiusBoilingTest()
        {
            float fahrenheit = 212F;
            float expected = 100F; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
            float actual;
            actual = Form1.FahrenheitToCelsius(fahrenheit);
            Assert.AreEqual(Math.Round(expected, 2), Math.Round(actual, 2));
            //Assert.Inconclusive("Verify the correctness of this test method.");
        }
```

Comment: We need more information. MSTest, NUnit, or something else? Integration- or unit-tests? By the way, do you have one test-project and one implementation project?

Comment: Are you running in Debug? step through the code, maybe something is blocking?

Comment: Can you show the test and the method under test? Code always helps.

Comment: I have 2 programs, one i KNOW works, but the tests down't on my PC, and will post my test in one second

Comment: What is the definition of `Form1.FahrenheitToCelsius`?

Comment: It's not the code, I am 100% certain it's a setting or some background thing in VS that is breaking the tests.

Comment: Can you step through the tests with a debugger the way @user2509738 suggests? There's no setting in VS that magically breaks your tests, but it's entirely possible that you have a test that doesn't run under certain conditions (especially since the method is in a class called `Form1`, which suggests potential involvement of UI code, which is a sure way to hang unit tests...). *Post the code...*

Answer (score 2):

Probably because you are tagging your tests wrong:

For NUnit,

```
[TestMethod()]
public void fahrenheitToCelsiusBoilingTest()
```

..should be:

```
[TestFixture] // <-- Make sure you have this too!
public MyTestClass { 

    [Test]
    public void fahrenheitToCelsiusBoilingTest()

}
```

`[TestMethod]` is the tag used for MSTest, which is a different test-framework; see [this for example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nnaderi/archive/2007/02/01/mstest-vs-nunit-frameworks.aspx), for a quick comparison.

**Update:**

Make sure you are refering to NUnit then: `using NUnit.Framework;`

If you haven't got NUnit yet, get it using the Nuget package manager:

Go: `View -> Other windows -> Package Manager Console`, and enter

```
PM> install-package nunit
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try your code in this way & it will resolve your problem :

```
[TestFixture]
public class NUnitTests
{
    [Test]
    public void fahrenheitToCelsiusBoilingTest()
    {
            float fahrenheit = 212F;
            float expected = 100F; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
            float actual;
            actual = Form1.FahrenheitToCelsius(fahrenheit);
            Assert.AreEqual(Math.Round(expected, 2), Math.Round(actual, 2));
            //Assert.Inconclusive("Verify the correctness of this test method.");
    }
 }
```